Why $(a+b)^* = (a^*b)^* a^*$
I have seen on a book that for regular expressions it holds the equality $(a+b)^* = (a^*b)^* a^*$ but I am not seeing why. It is clear that the language generated by $(a+b)^*$ contains $(a^*b)^* a^*$, but when take $x \in L((a+b)^*)=L(a+b)^*$ I do not see a clear way to express $x$ like a word of $L((a^*b)^* a^*)$, so any possible help or explanation would be appreciated.

"It is clear that the language generated by $(a+b)^∗$ contains $(a^∗b)^∗a^∗$" Would not a string like $bbbbb$ belong to the second language, but not the first?

@rus9384 No, it belongs to both of them. $(a+b)^* = \cup_{k=0}^\infty (a+b)^k$ where $(a+b)^k = { a_1 \dots a_k : a_j \in {a,b} }$ and $bbbbb \in (a+b)^5$

Consider any string $\omega$ that belongs to $(a+b)^*$. Now suppose $\omega$ contains $n$ number of $b$s. We can now partition $\omega = x_1 x_2 \dots x_n y$, where all $x_i$ are of the form $a^*b$ and $y = a^*$.

Every b in a string belonging to (a+b)* is preceded by 0, 1, 2 or more a's. And the last b is followed by 0, 1, 2 or more a's.

Just as a comment, it's also possible to show this purely algebraically, using Kozen's axioms for Kleene algebra.
To show that:
$$\displaystyle x^*\le y$$
It is sufficient to show that:
$$\displaystyle 1 + x y \le y$$
So to show:
$$\displaystyle (a+b)^* \le (a^* b)^* a^*$$
It is sufficient to show that:
$$\displaystyle 1 + (a+b) (a^* b)^* a^* \le (a^* b)^* a^*$$
Expanding the left-hand side gives:
$$\displaystyle 1 + a (a^* b)^* a^* + b (a^* b)^* a^*\le (a^* b)^* a^*$$
And now, you can show this by proving the three cases on the left separately:
$$\displaystyle \begin{eqnarray*} 1 & \le & (a^* b)^* a^*\\
a (a^* b)^* a^* & \le & (a^* b)^* a^*\\
b (a^* b)^* a^* & \le &(a^* b)^* a^*\end{eqnarray*}$$
The first and third are trivial, and the second can be shown by expanding the left-hand side again:
$$\displaystyle a (a^* b) a^* = a a^* + a a^* b (a^* b)^* a^*$$
and showing that both terms on the right-hand side are contained in $(a^* b)^* a^*$.

This is so interesting, in my books did not explain anything about algebraic propperties of regular expressions

If I do not bother you, can I ask you something? I am wondering if there is some way to find with this algebraic propperties the regular expression for the intersection of two Regular languages knowing their regular expressions

Personal opinion, I think it's easier to work with intersection and set difference using Brzozowski derivatives. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brzozowski_derivative
